# Data Not Refreshing when running script (NodeJs Lambda Alexa Skill)

Tags: json, node.js, lambda

I've created a Lambda project running with NodeJs. When I run the script it gets the values from my external website (JSON Data).

If I change the data and then re-run the script, it doesn't update the values until I run the script again.

So I have to run the script twice in order for the script to get the JSON data.

Does anyone know how to fix this, part of the script is below where it request to get the values from my server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get('http://1**.24.**.2*5/data.php', function(res){
var body = '';
res.on('data', function(data){
    res.body = "";
      body += data;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
      boatdata = JSON.parse(body);
    });
  }).on('error', function(e){
    console.log('Http Error: ' + e);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to fetch the data inside the Lambda handler method. It may not be executed otherwise. (It is executed upon initialization of the Lambda function, but subsequent calls to the function invoke only the handler method.)